# Why does Dumbledore compare Crouch Jr's Dark Mark to Harry's cut arm? Also, why does the cut then change to resemble a Dark Mark?

Tags: harry-potter, character-motivation

This happens at the end of *Goblet of Fire*, after Harry has returned from the graveyard through the Portkey. Crouch Jr then takes him to his office and is about to kill him before Dumbledore intervenes. He then reveals his Dark Mark to which Dumbledore requests to see Harry's arm.

Comment: Because the movies are nonsense. This doesn't happen in the books at all.

Comment: Does the cut really resemble the Dark Mark? Despite seeing it several times (though I really do not know why other than I must be extremely bored at the time ... that has to be the reason) I have never been able to see the resemblance. Maybe I need to screen capture it to see it or maybe it's too abstract for me to see. Am I the only one who doesn't see it?

Answer (score 7):

As said in the comments: this does not happen in the books, so we can only guess.

Dumbledore is kind of omniscient in the books and even more in the movies (as they are not able to describe in detail where he got all his knowledge from).

My best guess is, that Dumbledore most probably knows, what Voldemort needs to create a new body. He knows the formula and that it needs

> **WORMTAIL** <sup>*</sup>
>   Blood of the enemy forcibly taken.

Therefor he checks Harry for the existence of a wound that would show him, that his blood was taken.

Dumbledore furthermore reacts to what Crouch says:

> **BARTY JR**  <sup>*</sup>
>   I'll show you mine if you show me yours.
>
> *Barty Jr rolls up his sleeve to reveal a skull and snake marking.*
>
> **DUMBLEDORE**
>   Your arm Harry.
>
> **BARTY JR**
>   You know what this means don't you?
>   He's back. Lord Voldemort has returned.

So he suspects the wound to be on Harry's arm and finds it there. Barty draws the conclusion then...

<sub>*Both quotes taken from [this movie transcript](https://genius.com/Steven-kloves-harry-potter-and-the-goblet-of-fire-script-annotated)</sub>

Comment: I'm pretty sure Voldemort said the spell was something he came up with himself, so it would be odd for Dumbledore to know what it required.

Comment: Then again: movies are nonsense...

Comment: Even if Dumbledore knew the details of the potion the fact Voldemort is already back means he [Dumbledore] doesn't need to see the wound in order to confirm it was done; it's already happened at this point so what difference does it make?

Comment: At that moment Dumbledore did not yet know about Voldemort being back. He learnt it in that very moment...

Comment: I was about to ask a dupe of this question, someone on reddit suggested it was a bluff by Barty to see Harry's arm- Barty was not at the resurrection so he just got his confirmation.